# Estimating the parameters of a Beta distribution using the sample average and standard deviation

Tags: distributions, sample, fitting, beta-distribution

This is a simple question, but I just want to be sure.

Imagine that we have a sample of $n$ data $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ and that we want to fit them to a Beta distribution. Imagine that we have calculated $\bar{x}$ and $s_{n-1}$ (or simply $s$), where

$$
\bar{x}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{n}
$$
and
$$
s= \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}{n-1}} \text{.}
$$

I think that we can estimate the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the Beta distribution by $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$, respectively, where the values of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are obtained from the following equations:

$$ 
\bar{x} = \frac{\hat{\alpha}}{\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}} \quad,
\quad
s^2 = \frac{\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta}}{(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta})^2(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}+1)} \text{.}
$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (a version of) [*method of moments*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29).

It's certainly possible to estimate parameters this way, though it may not be as efficient as some other estimators.

Note, however, that if you want a four-parameter beta, rather than one on (0,1), things are more complicated.

In the case in your question you can simplify the calculations; note that $\frac{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}{s^2}=\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}+1=\hat{\alpha}(\frac{\hat{\beta}}{\hat{\alpha}}+1)+1$, 
and $1/\bar{x}=\frac{\hat{\beta}}{\hat{\alpha}}+1$.

From there we can readily obtain an equation just in $\hat{\alpha}$; once you have that you can immediately find $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: So, @Glen_b, do you mean that this estimation (the method of moments in this case) can be biased? I thought that it was somehow equivalent to the maximum likelihood method, in this case of the Beta distribution.

Comment: (i) Method of moments can certainly be biased, (maximum likelihood usually is as well), but that's not what I was getting at; I referred to *efficiency*, not bias. (ii) No, method of moments is *not* equivalent to maximum likelihood in general, and in the case of the beta they're certainly different.

Comment: I've seen an explanation of the MLE method for the parameters of a Beta distribution here: http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/point/Likelihood.html#bet, which also refers to a nice simulation experiment, but it deals with the case in which either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are supposed to be known. Then I've seen this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Beta_distribution#Two_unknown_parameters_2 . There I read that I can numerically solve a 2-equation system (this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/9/5/695e9b843d07f239ed9b833951c08818.png) in order to get the MLE of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. [...]

Comment: [...] Did I understand it right?  Now, my question is: Do statistic software such as Statgraphics use MLE methods in order to estimate parameters?

Comment: I answer my last question in the previous comment. According to a help document in Statgraphics, _"Estimates are obtained using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE)"_ (in the context of parameter estimation and distribution fitting  of uncensored data). So, thank you, @Glen_b, for your answer, which gave me some information I didn't know/remember and made me think and do some extra research.  ;)

Comment: The Wikipedia page on the Beta has a section that [discusses finding the MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Beta_distribution#Two_unknown_parameters_2) that's reasonably clear, though parts of it might be new to you.